# Prototype Framework Breaking Other Scripts

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a simple page that has a (non-Prototype) JavaScript pop-up for login.  It has been working fine.  But when I add the Prototype framework to the page the pop-up quits working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="recipes/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var imgnum = 1;

function nextimg() {
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  imgnum++;
  if (imgnum > 5) imgnum = 1;
  var nextimg = 'recipes/img/iphone_' + imgnum + '.png';
  var nextimg2 = 'recipes/img/iphone_' + (imgnum + 1) + '.png';
  imagepreload = new Image();
  imagepreload.src = nextimg2;
  $('iphoneimg').src=nextimg;
  /* ]]> */
} 
</script>
```

I have tried to move the JS include to the bottom, with no luck.  Any ideas?

Also, it works fine in IE but not Firefox or Safari.

Comment: Yes, Prototype tends to conflict with other scripts. Any specific error messages? And how come there is a "$('iphoneimg')" if there has not been any prototype/jquery there yet?

Comment: Did you check the script with Firebug? It will help you find problems like these.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, just not working on Firefox.  I did run Firebug but it did not throw any errors.

Comment: Was the `$('iphoneimg')` call already there before you started using Prototype?

Comment: Prototype doesn't 'tend' to conflict with other scripts any more than any other script would.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prototype takes the $ function that JQuery also uses (are you using JQuery?).

[See here](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)

Comment: No, I am not using jQuery only Prototype.

Comment: Sorry - but I need to plug FireBug.  Have you tried using it to debug the problem on FF?

Comment: Step into the function to the point where you have $('iphoneimg').src=nextimg; and examine the value of $('iphoneimg').

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the code for awhile I figured it out.  My pop-up login box is using a `toggle()` function.  So I renamed the `toggle` to `toggle_box` and the problem is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the 'iphoneimg' element exists on your page.

If firebug is not showing anything, add some `alert()` breakpoints to see where it silently fails.

Comment: Yes, it does I added the alert() through the code.  The login box is what is breaking not the prototype code.  So I need to look there.